# Raycast Masks not working Unity3D

Tags: unity, raycasting

I'm having a problem with filters/masks when raycasting.

I've created a LayerMask and then in the inspector selected the layer I want to ignore when Raycasting. however then I print out the name of the object hit by the raycast I am still getting hits on objects on the layer masked out, as well as on other layers.

```
public LayerMask rayMask;

RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit,rayMask)){
    Debug.Log (hit.collider.name);
}
```

I have paused the Game and checked that the object I'm getting a hit on is indeed on the layer in the mask.

Comment: Instead of marking you question with `[solved]` post an answer instead.

Comment: Seconding. Post your solution as an answer, and accept it when the options becomes available. It'll mark the question as solved, and stop the unanswered question system from bumping the question up to get an answer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry folks. First Post here on Stack Exchange.
Thought maybe after a while I could just mark one of your comments as an answer guess not.

So my solution was:

Physics.Raycast () needs 4 veriables in order to use a Layermask.
So i had to add a distance to the ray. i.e.

```
Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit,mathf.infinity,rayMask)
```

that got the layermask working Although it was the Inverse of what i thought, the ray hit only what was on the mask. So i added

```
rayMask = ~rayMask;
```

to invert the Layermask.